# Error building the vidyo.io-connector-react-native sample app

Tags: vidyo

I cloned the project and followed the insctructions in the readme that basically say to extract a zip and move to the right place. The built and got this error:

/Users/**/vidyo/vidyo.io-connector-react-native/ios/VidyoConnectorView.h:14:9: 'Lmi/VidyoClient/VidyoConnector_Objc.h' file not found

Is this a known issue when using the Vidyo react native SDK?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that it cannot find the public headers which are located inside. You need  to download the VidyoClientIOS/Android SDK and place it in the specified path.

Download the latest Vidyo.io Android & iOS SDK packages:

1. Unzip VidyoClient-AndroidSDK folder and move contents of `VidyoClient-AndroidSDK/lib/android` to `VidyoConnector-react-native/android/app/libs/android`
2. Unzip VidyoClient-iOSSDK folder and move contents of `VidyoClient-iOSSDK/lib/ios` to `VidyoConnector-react-native/ios/lib/ios`